# How to suppress nginx worker process notices?

Tags: logs, docker, nginx

**Note: Logging is disabled but the notices still occur!**

I want a clean log that only shows errors for my Docker containers but nginx is just flooding the command line with noise even though I **disable everything**, is there any elegant way (e.g. not using grep as an entry point) to disable those notices?

I am already using the `NGINX_ENTRYPOINT_QUIET_LOGS=1` environment variable, the `-q` parameter and **disabled the error log completely** (which is not the end goal but for testing only).

```
$ docker run -e "NGINX_ENTRYPOINT_QUIET_LOGS=1" nginx:alpine "nginx" "-q" "-g" "daemon off; error_log /dev/null emerg;"                        
2024/02/15 09:38:02 [notice] 1#1: using the "epoll" event method
2024/02/15 09:38:02 [notice] 1#1: nginx/1.25.4
2024/02/15 09:38:02 [notice] 1#1: built by gcc 12.2.1 20220924 (Alpine 12.2.1_git20220924-r10) 
2024/02/15 09:38:02 [notice] 1#1: OS: Linux 6.7.4-arch1-1
2024/02/15 09:38:02 [notice] 1#1: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1073741816:1073741816
2024/02/15 09:38:02 [notice] 1#1: start worker processes
2024/02/15 09:38:02 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 30
2024/02/15 09:38:02 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 31
2024/02/15 09:38:02 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 32
2024/02/15 09:38:02 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 33
2024/02/15 09:38:02 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 34
2024/02/15 09:38:02 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 35
2024/02/15 09:38:02 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 36
2024/02/15 09:38:02 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 37
2024/02/15 09:38:02 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 38
2024/02/15 09:38:02 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 39
2024/02/15 09:38:02 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 40
2024/02/15 09:38:02 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 41
2024/02/15 09:38:02 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 42
2024/02/15 09:38:02 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 43
2024/02/15 09:38:02 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 44
2024/02/15 09:38:02 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 45
2024/02/15 09:38:02 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 46
2024/02/15 09:38:02 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 47
2024/02/15 09:38:02 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 48
2024/02/15 09:38:02 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 49
2024/02/15 09:38:02 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 50
2024/02/15 09:38:02 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 51
2024/02/15 09:38:02 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 52
2024/02/15 09:38:02 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 53
^C2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 1#1: signal 2 (SIGINT) received, exiting
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 30#30: exiting
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 32#32: exiting
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 33#33: exiting
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 39#39: exiting
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 37#37: exiting
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 40#40: exiting
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 38#38: exiting
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 31#31: exiting
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 42#42: exiting
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 43#43: exiting
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 35#35: exiting
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 34#34: exiting
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 46#46: exiting
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 36#36: exiting
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 45#45: exiting
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 47#47: exiting
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 49#49: exiting
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 48#48: exiting
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 41#41: exiting
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 44#44: exiting
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 51#51: exiting
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 50#50: exiting
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 52#52: exiting
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 53#53: exiting
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 36#36: exit
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 33#33: exit
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 30#30: exit
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 49#49: exit
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 41#41: exit
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 37#37: exit
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 42#42: exit
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 43#43: exit
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 35#35: exit
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 52#52: exit
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 31#31: exit
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 34#34: exit
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 45#45: exit
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 44#44: exit
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 46#46: exit
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 39#39: exit
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 50#50: exit
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 32#32: exit
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 53#53: exit
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 40#40: exit
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 48#48: exit
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 51#51: exit
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 47#47: exit
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 38#38: exit
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 1#1: signal 14 (SIGALRM) received
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 1#1: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 40
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 1#1: worker process 40 exited with code 0
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 1#1: worker process 42 exited with code 0
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 1#1: signal 29 (SIGIO) received
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 1#1: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 42
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 1#1: worker process 39 exited with code 0
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 1#1: signal 29 (SIGIO) received
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 1#1: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 37
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 1#1: worker process 37 exited with code 0
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 1#1: worker process 46 exited with code 0
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 1#1: signal 29 (SIGIO) received
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 1#1: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 46
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 1#1: worker process 32 exited with code 0
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 1#1: worker process 48 exited with code 0
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 1#1: signal 29 (SIGIO) received
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 1#1: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 47
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 1#1: worker process 47 exited with code 0
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 1#1: signal 29 (SIGIO) received
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 1#1: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 44
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 1#1: worker process 44 exited with code 0
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 1#1: signal 29 (SIGIO) received
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 1#1: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 50
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 1#1: worker process 45 exited with code 0
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 1#1: worker process 50 exited with code 0
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 1#1: signal 29 (SIGIO) received
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 1#1: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 45
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 1#1: worker process 51 exited with code 0
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 1#1: signal 29 (SIGIO) received
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 1#1: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 33
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 1#1: worker process 33 exited with code 0
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 1#1: worker process 43 exited with code 0
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 1#1: worker process 34 exited with code 0
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 1#1: signal 29 (SIGIO) received
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 1#1: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 34
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 1#1: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 52
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 1#1: worker process 52 exited with code 0
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 1#1: signal 29 (SIGIO) received
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 1#1: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 31
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 1#1: worker process 31 exited with code 0
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 1#1: signal 29 (SIGIO) received
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 1#1: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 36
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 1#1: worker process 36 exited with code 0
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 1#1: worker process 41 exited with code 0
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 1#1: worker process 53 exited with code 0
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 1#1: signal 29 (SIGIO) received
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 1#1: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 49
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 1#1: worker process 30 exited with code 0
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 1#1: worker process 38 exited with code 0
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 1#1: worker process 49 exited with code 0
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 1#1: signal 29 (SIGIO) received
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 1#1: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 30
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 1#1: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 35
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 1#1: worker process 35 exited with code 0
2024/02/15 09:38:04 [notice] 1#1: exit
```

P.S.: The problem starts with nginx version 1.20.0. Version 1.19.10 (the latest 1.19 version) does not have those notices but out of concern for security vulnerabilities I do not want to use such an old version.

However this change is not mentioned in the changelog http://nginx.org/en/CHANGES-1.20:

```
Changes with nginx 1.20.0                                        20 Apr 2021
    *) 1.20.x stable branch.
```

P.P.S.: All logging is disabled for this test using `error_log /dev/null emerg;`, the messages seem to be emitted by nginx outside of the normal logging.

Comment: What does your Nginx configuration look like with regards to logging? One usually select the log level with the `error_log` setting (see https://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#error_log).

Comment: @Kusalananda: I deactivated all logging for this test using `error_log /dev/null emerg;`, the messages seem to be emitted by nginx outside of the normal logging environment.

Comment: Are you using a public Nginx container? That would make it a lot easier for us to help you I think.

Comment: @Kusalananda: Yes, I am using the public image nginx:alpine from Docker Hub, I have written the exact command line statements including parameters in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Docker image that you use, `nginx:alpine`, uses an Nginx configuration that includes the line

```
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
```

You should extract the provided configuration file, modify it, and then start the container with your modified configuration file mounted in the correct place.

1. Get the provided configuration file by simply running `cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf` in the container and redirecting the output to a file (here I use `my-nginx.conf` in the current directory):

   ```
   docker run --rm --entrypoint=cat nginx:alpine /etc/nginx/nginx.conf >my-nginx.conf
   ```
2. Modify the file with your favourite editor, changing the word `notice` to `error` on the line indicated above.  This will make the service log error messages or messages with higher priority.  With GNU `sed`, you may do this like so:

   ```bash
   sed -i '/^error_log.*notice;/ s/notice/error/' my-nginx.conf
   ```
3. Start the container with the modified configuration file mounted (read-only) at `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.  Here, I'm just testing with `run --rm`:

   ```
   docker run --rm -v "$PWD/my-nginx.conf":/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro nginx:alpine
   ```

When I do this locally, I get the following output, showing that the log level is indeed no longer `notice`:

```
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Enabled listen on IPv6 in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Sourcing /docker-entrypoint.d/15-local-resolvers.envsh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
```

---

See also: The "Customize configuration" section of the Nginx Docker Hub page: https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx

Comment: I thought that environment variables would have higher priority but apparently that's not the case, your solution works great! However get it into a single line in a Dockerfile I reduced it to `RUN sed -i "s|notice|error|" /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.

Comment: @KonradHöffner I added a suggestion for a slightly more restrictive `sed` command in the answer. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @KonradHöffner I think that the `NGINX_ENTRYPOINT_QUIET_LOGS` variable only affects the entry point script. I have never seen the Nginx service itself make use of this variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use `error_log warn;` in production. The `notice` and higher levels are only suitable for development.

Comment: I have already turned off all logging, the notice message seems to ignore my log level.